# How update php5 to php7 (OSX Sierra)

Tags: php

I'm following this tutorial (https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/upgrade-php-mac-os-x/) to update php5 to php7 and I have this folder `usr/local/php5-7.0.12-20161101-102255` but when I asks in Terminal >`php -version` I get `5.6.25`. I don't know how to use the php 7 installed

regards.

Comment: I use brew to handle my php versions: https://developerjack.com/blog/2016/08/26/Installing-PHP71-with-homebrew/

Comment: Are you sure you've installed PHP/7 in a folder called `php5`?

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, you may try [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install packages. For instance, PHP 5.6, PHP 7.0, PHP 7.1 or any other ones can be installed with similar command

`$brew install php70`

Also, remember to use `/usr/local/bin` within your `$PATH` to ensure proper version of PHP will be used. Such as set following in your `~/.bashrc` (in case you use Bash shell

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: I have executed this command >sudo nano /etc/paths and I see that "usr/local/bin/" is included. After I have installed with Homebrew php70 and now I have this folder "usr/local/Cellar/php70. I understand that I should add this path so I could run php7?

Comment: you don't need to use sudo to adjust your user $PATH. Just edit your `~/.bashrc` to append. For more details, you can use `brew info php70` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I have already found and understood the solution. Once installed with homebrew php7 and therefore the /usr/local/Cellar/php70 folder has been created. What you have to do is to have the path /usr/local/ bin in the $ PATH. There is a php file that is a symbolic link to the php folder of the version to use, ie if that symbolic link points to /usr/loca/Cellar/php70 php --version will give you version 7. But it does not You need to add the / usr / local / Cellar / php70 path to $ PATH. Regards